# Can I run a NEAR node with a higher gas limit for view calls?

Tags: nearprotocol

Currently, the view method calls [are limited](https://github.com/near/nearcore/blob/7e24d5d758be41ff12528964ebdcad12e32b990d/runtime/runtime/src/state_viewer/mod.rs#L245) by the protocol config option [`runtime_config.wasm_config.limit_config.max_gas_burnt_view`](https://github.com/near/nearcore/blob/7e24d5d758be41ff12528964ebdcad12e32b990d/nearcore/res/mainnet_genesis.json#L184). Can there be an option to configure it per node instead of on the protocol level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. There is a WIP pull request to address this issue https://github.com/near/nearcore/pull/4381